# Connecting to HTTPS from within eclipse plugin throws Exception

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl, https, eclipse-plugin

I have a piece of code within my plugin as follows:

```
    String url = "https://...";

    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.connect();
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
```

This code works perfectly when I use it in a standalone Java application. But it throws the following exception when I try to runit from within the plugin:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported record version SSLv2Hello
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.checkRecordVersion(InputRecord.java:552)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:565)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:529)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:954)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at test.plugin.Activator.testSSLConnection(Activator.java:57)
    at test.plugin.Activator.start(Activator.java:42)
```

Anything I should configure to make the code work from within the plugin?
I did not find any solutions in the eclipse plugin context related to SSL here or on the eclipse forums.

Comment: Did you try the Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files?

Comment: @ServerSideCat Is this a standard practice in configuring a client application like eclipse to work with SSL? Looks like too much work for users using the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to this issue:

The server was running on Java 7, while the client was running on Java 8.
Once I switched my eclipse runtime to Java 7, the issue was resolved.